# Adding "request change" button to Sharepoint Task

Tags: tasks

I have created a workflow that is triggered when a new item is created in a SharePoint list. This workflow starts a task process with the approval board. However, there are only two options for these tasks: Approve OR Reject.

Is it possible to create another option like "Request Change" in order to return the task to sender so he/she can make the modifications according to the feedback provided?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is in a SharePoint Designer Workflow action under "Start Approval Process". You have the option to allow a third button called "Request Change" that will send an email to the requestor/initiator to request a change.

Comment: Where can I find the option to enable this buttom? I am using Sharepoint 2013 and my task is being created in the workflow under "Start a Task Process".

Comment: instead of Start a Task Process, use Start an Approval Process, you will see it under Allow request changes, when you click into the action

Comment: The “Start Approval Workflow” action is deprecated in SharePoint 2013.: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2eec837-c876-4b4c-85a4-c98c338522fb/approval-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization